# how to cancel a specific notification in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

my app is a reminder app, user will add tasks with time that he chose and he will get a notification.
tasks will be added in a Listview.builder and the id will be generated randomly

my problem is how the notification will be canceled if he for example removed the third task.

that's the code for adding and removing the tasks that I made:

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Task> tasks = [];
  int id = Random().nextInt(1000);


  void addNewTask(String newTaskTile , String date ,){
    tasks.add(Task(name: newTaskTile , date: date ,));
      notifyListeners();

  }


  void deleteTask(Task task){
    NotificationService().cancelNotifications(id);
    tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want to achieve. What should happen when the user removes the notification from where?

Comment: when the user removes the task, I want the notification got removed too because i still get notification even after i delete the task